# Hibernate multiple columns IN clause Miscrosft SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

When I try to get all the rows from a table using my JPA repository the query Hibernate is generating is like this:

```
Select field1, field2, ... from ... where (field1, field2) IN (select f1, f2 from ....)
```

It is working properly when my db is PostgreSQL. Now I am about to migrate to Ms SQL Server. My repository looks like this

```
 @Override
public List<VesselVisit> getAllVisits() {
    return this.visitsRepository.findAll();
}
```

The data model has a parent entity that and has a relationship OneToMany to the children using a composite key.

It is not possible to implement this using SQL Server?

Comment: are you planning to entity framework post migration ?

Comment: No I am not, I am obligated to user hibernate...

Comment: could you please share hibernate code ?

Comment: Hibernate query is generated automatically, I am not putting anything on top, it is just a repository class implementing CrudRespository

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Inner Join Instead of In Operator in SQL Server For achieving it.

Comment: I would not like to write manually the query, I want Hibernate to do it, actually, the query is generated automatically and it worked on PostgreSQL, but no os Ms SQL...

Comment: in SQL server Multiple columns not allowed in an operator.

Comment: I know, but this query is automatically generated, there isn't any configuration that allow hibernate to transform this query in sql into a join for example? I would not like to write the query manually...